# Determine whether an integer is palindrome or not without using extra space

Tags: c

I wrote the following function for finding whether an integer is a palindrome or not without requiring any extra space:

```
int isPalindrome(int x) 
{
    int i=0,j,y,z;
    if(x<0)
        return 0;
    for(i=0;;)
    {
        if((**y**=x/pow(10,i)) > 0)      //Variable 'y' here
        {
            i++;
        }
        else 
            break;
    }
    printf("i=%d\n",i);

    for(;i>0;)
    {
        if(x%10!=(**z**=x/pow(10,i-1)))     //variable 'z' here
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            x=x%(int)pow(10,i-1);
            x=x/10;
            i=i-2;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here returning 1 means it is palindrome and 0 means not.

But I found that when I remove the variable **y** and **z** from the statements in the code, the code does not give desired result. What may be the reason behind it?

Comment: Are you sure you want this tagged as `c++-cli`? That tag has much lower viewership than `c` or `c++`, and there's nothing C++/CLI-specific in this code...

Answer (score 2):

when variables y or z removed than expression type changes from int to double.

- type of expression 'x/pow(10,i)' is double
- type of expression 'y = x/pow(10, i)' is int
- 'z = x/pow(10,i-1)' - int
- 'x/pow(10,i-1)' - double